# detecting collisions on the canvas

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to make a game where collisions happen between the protagonist and the antagonist. I cant get the collision to work though, i've tried using the x and y position then the x and y positions plus the width and the height of the protagonist and the antagonist

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var PX = 10;
var PY = 10;
var PW = 10;
var PH = 10;
var P = PX + PY;
var EX1 = 100;
var EY1 = 100;
var EW1 = 10;
var EH1 = 10;
var E1 = EX1 + EY1;

window.addEventListener("keydown", charMove);
window.addEventListener("keyup", charMove);
window.addEventListener("keypress", charMove);

window.onload = function() {
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.style.background = "black";
var framesPerSecond = 30;
setInterval(function() {
 draw();
 move();
}, 1000/framesPerSecond);
}

function draw() {
 //EX context.fillRect(PosX, PosY, width, height);
 //draws protagonist
 context.beginPath();
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 context.fillStyle = "blue"
 context.fillRect(PX, PY, PW, PH);
 context.stroke();
 context.closePath();
 //draws antagonist(s)
 context.beginPath();
 context.fillStlyle = "red";
 context.fillRect(EX1, EY1, EW1, EH1);
 context.stroke();
 context.closePath();
}
function move() {
}
function charMove(){
 var x = event.which || event.keyCode;

 if(x == 37){
  PX -= 1;
 }
 if(x == 38){
  PY -= 1;
 }
 if(x == 39){
  PX += 1; 
 }
 if(x == 40){
  PY += 1;
 }
}
//detect collision
setInterval(function() {
 if(PX > EX1 || PX + PW < EX1 + EW1 && PY + PH > EY1 + EH1 || PY + PH < EY1 + EH1){
  window.alert("collision");
 }

}, 1);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas width="500px" height="500px" id="canvas" class="canvas">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula for collision is wrong.

This problem is called Axis Aligned Bounding Box collision.

Two AABBs collide if their projections to each axis collide. In your 2-dimensinal case you have to consider the horizontal and vertical projections.

The projections are segments of 1-d space. Collision for those is very easy: if the start or the end of a segment is on the other they collide. Formally `start2 <= start1 <= end2 or start2 <= end1 <= end2`

In code:

```
intersects([p.x, p.x + p.width], [e.x, e.x + e.width]) && intersects([p.y, p.y + p.height], [e.y, e.y + e.height])
```

where

```
function intersects(seg1, seg2) {
    return contains(seg1, seg2[0]) || contains(seg1, seg2[1])
}
function contains(segment, point) {
    return segment[0] <= point && point <= segment[1]
}
```

Comment: do you have any example code like a webpage that could help me. I'm more of a hands on learner.

Comment: The code I wrote should work with yours. If you have trouble understanding it, try drawing one- and two-dimensional collisions on paper.